# .httaccess 301 redirect subdomain with path wildcards

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to 301 redirect URL's I was using on my old website/platform to my new website on Shopify.

**Old url structure:**

https://shop.olddomain.com/path/name-of-page

What I would like to have is a wildcard for http/https, because the platform changed my website from insecure to secure back when Google started ranking based on that.

I would also need a wildcard for /path/name-of-page, because I have hundreds of URL's with that structure and I'm not trying to map each of those URL's to the new URL's. Basically, my goal is to make sure those old URL's don't go to a dead end 404, and are redirected to the new website homepage.

So http/https://shop.olddomain.com/* should redirect to https://newdomain.com

Comment: You have to implement a simple redirection rule for that. So what is your actual issue? Why can't you simply do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` for `shop.olddomain.com` place

`Redirect 301 /shopoldpath https://newdomain.com`